# Using animation in android 4.0

Tags: android, animation

I am using this code to animate childViews in a ViewGroup on screen:

```
    zoom_in.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            viewGroup.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewGroup.getChildAt(i).clearAnimation();
            if(i<5)
            {
                i++;
                viewGroup.getChildAt(i).startAnimation(animation);
            }
            else
            {
                i=0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    zoom_out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            viewGroup.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            viewGroup.getChildAt(i).clearAnimation();
            if(i<5)
            {
                i++;
                viewGroup.getChildAt(i).startAnimation(animation);
            }
            else
            {
                viewGroup.getChildAt(i).startAnimation(zoom_in);
                i=0;
            }
        }
    });
```

The animation zoom_in and zoom_out are simple zoom in and zoom out animations. When I run this code on Android 4.2 or higher it works perfectly. But on lower then it doesnot work similarly. Can anyone explain me or provide any solution for this problem. I want it to work similar on all devices 4.0 and higher.